# how to add Images stacally in telescope app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to add image statically in telescope app on categories.html.
I was try to add image statically but i will take only predefined images. My code is as follow:

Comment: Please elaborate..Your question sounds like that everyone knows about what are there in categories.html

Comment: What is the `telescope app`, what is in the `categories.html`? Show us your code

Comment: Where is the following code?

Comment: <template name="categories_menu">
/*this code is for take category name */
<!--    <div class="posts-views-nav ">          
        {{#if hasCategories}}
        {{> menuComponent menuName="categories" menuItems=menuItems menuMode=menuMode}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>-->
    <div>
/*this code is for take category name end*/
    </div>
</template>

Comment: <template name="categories_menu">
/* here code for display image statically inplace of category name*/
        <img src="/packages/telescope_getting-started/content/images/stackoverflow.png" alt="image1" width="46px" height="46px"/>
        <img src="/packages/telescope_getting-started/content/images/telescope.png" alt="image1" width="46px" height="46px"/>
        /* here code for display image statically inplace of category name*/
    </div>
</template>

Comment: Telescope is same as meteor app